# Class Declaration - public and default

Tags: java

I would like to inquire if a class declaration in java can only be `public` and *default*?

I have read that there can only one `public` class inside a file and that file should be the name of the class.

For example `Test.java`

```
public class Test {

}
```

But I observed that in a class I can have no `public` class but can have many *default* classes.

For example `Exam.java`

```
class Exam {

}

class Examination {

}
```

Why is it that I can only have one `public` class but can have many *default* class inside one file?

Comment: A class can only be declared public or package private (in case, no modified is applied to its declaration, it is package private). A class cannot be declared `private` or `protected` unless it is an inner class or a static nested class. A public class requires a class saved in a file with same name as the class name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is it that I can only have one public class but can have many
>   default class inside one file?

[7.6. Top Level Type Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> This restriction implies that there must be at most one such type per
>   compilation unit. **This restriction makes it easy for a Java compiler
>   to find a named class within a package**. In practice, many programmers
>   choose to put each class or interface type in its own compilation
>   unit, whether or not it is public or is referred to by code in other
>   compilation units.

If a class doesn't have a modifier (default modifier), it can only be accessed from the same package.

Answer (score 3):

This is a design decision as pointed out by another answerer. This helps you organize the code in long run. You can have public inner classes though.